# How to implement this oscillation function

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

What would be a fast way to implent this osscilation function. 
A signature would look like this:

`public static double Calculate(UInt64 currentCounter, uint duration, uint inDuration, uint outDuration)`

And the result should be a double that as currentCounter advances, ossciates between 0 and 1. The osscialtion speed is defines by the `duration` parameter (the number of ticks for a single osccilation). Similarily the ascent and descent speed is defines via `inDUration` and `outDuration` (`inDUration` + `outDuration`).

[alt text http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/9457/graphuf.jpg](http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/9457/graphuf.jpg)

The x-Axis of this graph would of course be `currentCounter`.

Comment: How is the function defined between `inDuration` and (`Duration` - `outDuration`)? Is it zero or simply not defined?

Comment: What is the oscillation function during inDuration and outDuration? (Is it linear, X^2, sin(X)...?)

Comment: Shouldn't `currentCounter` parameter be `double` or `float`?

Comment: Between n in and out it is 0 for some time. Between out and in it is 1 for some time (yeah the drawing is wrong here). For simplicity the in and out function can be linear. But some easein and easout (lik in a sinus function) would be cool.

Comment: @Darin currentCounter is just integer. It is a discrete incrementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** - Here's a new function that includes staying at 1.0 between `outDuration` and the the next `inDuration`.  Note that I've changed your function signature - the input parameters are now `inDuration`, `holdDuration`, and `outDuration`.  The function stays at 0 between `inDuration` and `outDuration` for `holdDuration` samples, then stays at 1.0 after `outDuration` for another `holdDuration` samples.  The ramps are half-Hann functions again, you can change them as desired.

```
public static double Calculate(UInt64 currentCounter, uint inDuration, uint holdDuration, uint outDuration)
{
    UInt64 curTime;
    double ret;

    curTime = currentCounter % (inDuration + 2*holdDuration + outDuration); //this wrapping should really be handled by the caller

    if (curTime < inDuration)
    {
        ret = 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.Cos(2.0 * Math.PI * (inDuration - curTime) / (2.0 * inDuration)));
    }
    else if (curTime < inDuration + holdDuration)
    {
        ret = 0.0;
    }
    else if (curTime < inDuration + holdDuration + outDuration)
    {
        ret = 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.Cos(2.0 * Math.PI * (curTime - inDuration - holdDuration) / (2.0 * outDuration)));
    }
    else
    {
        ret = 1.0;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This has the same periodicity features as the previous version.

Here's a graph showing two cycles of the function.  The test loop was

```
for (ctr = 0; ctr < 20000; ctr++)
    Calculate(ctr, 2500, 2250, 3000);
```

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/4443/oscfnxn2.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/4443/oscfnxn2.png)

**First version**
I'm a big fan of the [Hann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function) for stuff like that.  It's continuous and differentiable, if that's a concern.  Here's a simple implementation:

```
public static double Calculate(UInt64 currentCounter, uint duration, uint inDuration, uint outDuration)
{
    UInt64 curTime;
    double ret;

    //should check that inDuration + outDuration <= duration
    curTime = currentCounter % duration; //this wrapping should really be handled by the caller

    if (curTime < inDuration)
    {
        ret = 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.Cos(2.0 * Math.PI * (inDuration - curTime) / (2.0 * inDuration)));
    }
    else if (curTime >= (duration - outDuration))
    {
        ret = 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.Cos(2.0 * Math.PI * (outDuration + duration - curTime) / (2.0 * outDuration)));
    }
    else
    {
        ret = 1.0;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Here's a sample graph.  This was generated with the loop

```
for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10000; ctr++)
    Calculate(ctr, 10000, 2500, 3000);
```

[Graph with duration = 10000, in = 2500, out = 3000 http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/2969/oscfnxn.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/2969/oscfnxn.png)

The function descends from 1.0 to 0 from index `0` to `inDuration`, stays at 0 until index `duration-outDuration`, then ascends to 1.0 at index `duration`, so it is exactly periodic in 'duration' samples.

I didn't understand your comment "Between out and in it is 1 for some time."  Don't you need another parameter to specify the hold time?

Comment: It is osscilating after the first period (after 10000) instead of 0 it holds 1 (for the same time as it held 0 in the first period).

Comment: Currently I am using a streched sinus where the top and bottom amplitude a are cut off using `Math.Min,Math.Max` and

Answer (score 2):

As the commenter points out, you have to know the functions.
The program structure would be something like:

```
// Use modulo to get the counter within the range of the first duration
var phaseCounter = currentCounter % duration;

// Use the appropriate function
if( phaseCounter < inDuration )
{
  return InFunction( phaseCounter, inDuration );
}
if( phaseCounter > duration - outDuration )
{
  // Normalize the phaseCounter to the domain of definition for OutFunction()
  var outDurationOffset = duration - outDuration;
  return OutFuntion( phaseCounter - outDurationOffset, outDuration );
}
return 0;
```

As you can see, you have to fill out `InFunction()` and `OutFunction()`.
They both get two parameters, the x position *in their domain of definition* and their domain of definition. This way it should be easy to implement the functions.

**EDIT:**
The [quadratic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function) could be an *example* for your `InFunction`:

```
double InFunction( uint current, uint range )
{
  return Math.Pow( ( current / range ) - 1, 2 );
}
```

By dividing current by range you get a value between 0 and 1 - which will make sure that the result is between 0 and 1, too (as you specified).